# Unexpected condition outcome in a ksh script

Tags: shell, ksh

The below code is not working.

I've given explanation for all the lines:

```
#!/bin/ksh
cat example.txt | while read LINE                 # reading line from file
do
    var=$LINE                                     # assigning line to variable
    echo $var                                     # printing the line
    H_OR_T="${var:0:6}"                           # taking substring from the line 
    echo $H_OR_T                                  # printing the substring
```

up to here the code is working fine.

If H_OR_T variable holds the hardcoded value (i.e., M$9001 kindly take a look on if condition below) I should enter the loop. But here I'm getting arithmetical errors.

```
    if [[ $H_OR_T = "M$9001" ] || [ $H_OR_T = "M$9002" ]]; 
       then
       echo "************** MOVING HEADER OR TRAILER RECORD TO DOMESTIC FILE ************"
       awk '{print $0}' example.txt > domestic.txt
    else
       echo "**************** MOVING RECORD TO LOGGER FILE **********************"
       awk '{print $0}' example.txt > logger.txt
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Not a ksh expert but I think you have two problems in your code.

First problem: You have to single quote `M$9001` otherwise the shell will try to expand `$9001`.

Second problem: You do not nest `[ ]` inside `[ ]`. Either use `[[ ]]` or two `[ ]`.

You should also quote `$H_OR_T` just in case it expands to something funny.

Here is your code probably fixed:

```
if [[ "$H_OR_T" = 'M$9001' || "$H_OR_T" = 'M$9002' ]];
```

Or to be POSIX compliant and more portable:

```
if [ "$H_OR_T" = 'M$9001' ] || [ "$H_OR_T" = 'M$9002' ];
```

Note that there are subtle differences between `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`. The ksh documenation is a bit sparse on this topic. This is the best I found: http://www.kornshell.com/doc/faq.html question number 10.

> Q10.  What is the difference between `[...]` and `[[...]]`?
>
> A10.  The `[[...]]` is processed as part of the shell grammar     whereas
>   `[...]` is processed like any other command.  Operators and operands are
>   detected when the command is  read, not after expansions are
>   performed.  The shell does not    do word splitting or pathname
>   generation inside  `[[...]]`.     This allows patterns to be specified for
>   string matching   purposes.

Comment: I think the preferred form is `if [...] || [...]`. According to [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D), this form is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @JosephR. I totally agree with you. People don't seem to read that wiki much often. `[` is a POSIX compliant keyword. ksh/bash suggest you use `[[` keyword in stead when you are writing for bash or ksh. `if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]` is  #sh.

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes for M$9001 if you are comparing with an exact value.

```
if [[ "$H_OR_T" = 'M$9001' ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more problems with this script. The useless use of `cat` is one of the examples. If we take the first part of the script we could have written it as

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < example.txt
```

Taking the `if.. else` part, what is the use of `awk {print $0}'`

```
if [[ "$H_OR_T" == 'M$9001' ]]; then
 ....
 ....
fi
```

In this case 'M$9001' is taken literally.